# Need PHP Help: Trying to Pull MySQL Data From Record Matching Variable. Variable is Set by If-Then Statements. Partially Works

Tags: php, mysql, variables, if-statement

Let me start by saying that I am really new to php.  I'm just learning to code with it.  As such, if any has any suggestions of more efficient ways to set up this code, I'll gladly accept them.

Okay, on to the issue:

For this site, we have a script that checks a session, a cookie and a database for a name.  If the name is found in any of these places, it is assigned to a variable.  If not, the name is taken from either the URL or a user submission then added to the database then cookie.  This is all accomplished with if-then-elseif statements, and everything seems to work fine on all pages except the registration page.  The registration page is the only page that actually uses the information pulled from this script.  All other pages simply check for the cookie and db record, then create them if not found.

The registration page is supposed to take the name variable from the previous script, check the database for a record where the name equals the name variable.  This script first checks for a name submission (from a separate form on this page).  If one is found, it sets the name variable equal to the name submission.  Next, it checks for a session then pulls the name variable from a session variable.  Third, it checks for either a name variable from the previous script.  It either comes from the cookie, the database or from the variables set when both of these entries were created.

Here is the problem:  a variable pulled from the session, or a variable pulled from a cookie always pull up the correct information.  However, the information won't pull up at all for a submission name, name from the database, or variable set when the cookie/db was created.  I set up an echo statement to show the name variable right before it is run in the DB query, and the names always show up correctly.  However, nothing appears to be pulled from the DB.  Here is the DB query:

```
echo $name_variable."<br>";
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db WHERE name='$name_variable' OR email='$name_variable'");
```

Any ideas what I can do to fix this?  I'm hoping this is just something simple I've overlooked.  I can post the code if need be, but it is rather long.

Comment: Can you give an example value of `$name_variable` ?

Comment: Could you please add some sort of a diagram or other visual aids of your design? I wish SO have some mechanism for us to easily add diagrams.

Comment: What that query returns? Did you try to echo it just to see if your `$name_variable` is set?

Comment: Is the table name db? And please provide the rest of the php/mysql code.

Comment: Can you try escaping the input with `mysql_real_escape_string()`? Or use `mysqli` and [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: please don't use `mysql_*` functions, it's deprecated (see [*red box*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)) and vulnerable to sql-injection. Use [*PDO*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [*MySQLi*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Answer (score 1):

$query=mysql_query("SE......

are you doing mysql_fetch_assoc

then mysql_array

to acess the variables with index.. please provide more code where things are not working .

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db WHERE name='".$name_variable."' OR email='".$name_variable."'");
```

Comment: Why? Interpolation should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Wow...I hate to admit it, but it was just a newbie error.

The database is opened with an include file.  This page has multiple includes, and one of them ALSO included the database file (with a require_once function).  This page also opened the database (with require_once) to compare data.

Anyway, I changed the required_once on this page to just required and everything worked perfectly.

Thanks to everyone who responded!